# Embedded Jetty NotUtf8Exception

Tags: jetty, url-encoding, embedded-jetty

We are running a web application embedded in a jetty container. On a jsp there is a jsp:forward. The values of the jsp:param are `ISO-8859-1`. How can I tell Jetty, that the URL is ISO-8859-1?

The system property `org.eclipse.jetty.util.UrlEncoding.charset` is not working. `org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! incomplete UTF8 sequence...` is thrown.

Here is an example of the jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
...
<jsp:forward page="/forwardToAServlet">
<jsp:param name="param1" value="an+example+with+an+umlaut+gr%F6%DFere" />
</jsp:forward>
```

And here the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! incomplete UTF8 sequence
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable.checkState(Utf8Appendable.java:232) ~[jetty-util-9.1.0.v20131115.jar:9.1.0.v20131115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8StringBuffer.getStringBuffer(Utf8StringBuffer.java:65) ~[jetty-util-9.1.0.v20131115.jar:9.1.0.v20131115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.UrlEncoded.decodeString(UrlEncoded.java:843) ~[jetty-util-9.1.0.v20131115.jar:9.1.0.v20131115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.UrlEncoded.decodeTo(UrlEncoded.java:221) ~[jetty-util-9.1.0.v20131115.jar:9.1.0.v20131115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.mergeQueryString(Request.java:2172) ~[jetty-server-9.1.0.v20131115.jar:9.1.0.v20131115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:229) ~[jetty-server-9.1.0.v20131115.jar:9.1.0.v20131115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:101) ~[jetty-server-9.1.0.v20131115.jar:9.1.0.v20131115]
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:792) ~[javax.servlet.jsp-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.template.test_005jsp_jsp._jspService(test_005jsp_jsp.java:84) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111) ~[javax.servlet.jsp-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411) ~[javax.servlet.jsp-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473) ~[javax.servlet.jsp-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377) ~[javax.servlet.jsp-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:696) ~[jetty-servlet-9.1.0.v20131115.jar:9.1.0.v20131115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:526) [jetty-servlet-9.1.0.v20131115.jar:9.1.0.v20131115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) ~[jetty-server-9.1.0.v20131115.jar:9.1.0.v20131115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:586) ~[jetty-security-9.1.0.v20131115.jar:9.1.0.v20131115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221) ~[jetty-server-9.1.0.v20131115.jar:9.1.0.v20131115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1110) ~[jetty-server-9.1.0.v20131115.jar:9.1.0.v20131115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:453) [jetty-servlet-9.1.0.v20131115.jar:9.1.0.v20131115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183) ~[jetty-server-9.1.0.v20131115.jar:9.1.0.v20131115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1044) ~[jetty-server-9.1.0.v20131115.jar:9.1.0.v20131115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) ~[jetty-server-9.1.0.v20131115.jar:9.1.0.v20131115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:261) ~[jetty-server-9.1.0.v20131115.jar:9.1.0.v20131115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:101) ~[jetty-server-9.1.0.v20131115.jar:9.1.0.v20131115]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at net.bull.javamelody.JspWrapper.invoke(JspWrapper.java:149) ~[javamelody-core-1.43.0.jar:1.43.0]
    at net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$DelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:271) ~[javamelody-core-1.43.0.jar:1.43.0]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy51.forward(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:241) ~[tiles-servlet-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    ... 94 common frames omitted
```

I've found in the source code in the method mergeQueryString(String query) of class org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request following:

```
UrlEncoded.decodeTo(query,parameters, StandardCharsets.UTF_8,-1); //have to assume UTF-8 because we can't know otherwise
```

So in method URLEncoded.decodeTo() UTF-8 is used an not the encoding set with System.setProperty("org.eclipse.jetty.util.UrlEncoding.charset", "ISO-8859-1")

Can I solve this somehow? Any ideas? :-)

Comment: Can you post (in your question) an example of the problematic JSP / forward?

Comment: Include the complete stacktrace too.

Comment: Note: the use of `org.eclipse.jetty.util.UrlEncoding.charset` System property only works from command line, not embedded via a `System.setProperty()` call.

Comment: Hi Joakim,
thanks for your response. :-) 
I've added an example and the stacktrace to the question. The System.setProperty works and is right (i.e. ISO-8859-1) in class UrlEncoded.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is a bug in Jetty 9.1.0.

So I filed it at https://bugs.eclipse.org/423692

The short of it is that a `Dispatcher.forward()` needs to perform a `Request.mergeQueryString()`, but as that is going to decode the incoming query string, [that decoding step is hardcoded at UTF8](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.1.0.v20131115/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Request.java#L2172) (the default for HTTP), which prevents the overridden encoding/charset that you specified in the `org.eclipse.jetty.util.UrlEncoding.charset` property.

The HTTP spec leads on the Jetty project will evaluate if this is a valid bug in Jetty or a requirement of the HTTP spec and must be left as is.

Follow that bug, and meanwhile consider using UTF-8 everywhere, as that's the de facto encoding for the web.  (eg: Early indications on HTTP/2 spec also indicate that content/document encoding will be left alone, but protocol encoding will be strictly enforced at UTF-8)